# i am use OAuth 2.0 Flow to get Authorization code of docusign. but why after hit API appear docusign login screen

Tags: oauth-2.0, docusignapi

i am use OAuth 2.0 Flow to get Authorization code. but why after hit API appear docusign login screen.
and after login we get Authorization code. we need Authorization code but can't login docusign again.
please help me.

Comment: Please make your English understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary: the user only needs to authenticate once.

Since your users are present, you should use authorization code grant. Use scopes `signature%20extended` (the %20 is a space)

Then use the refresh token when the access token expires.

Since you use the extended scope, you'll receive a new refresh token good for another 30 days. So if you use DocuSign API once a month, your user will never again need to authenticate.

JWT is only for cases where the user is not present to authenticate.

Answer (score 1):

[Auth Code Grant](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-code-grant) does require that the user log in. The token you get is only valid for 8 hours and in the subsequent attempts, you will need to log-in again.
You can use a refresh token to obtain a new access token (and a new refresh token) but users still need to authentication with Auth Code Grant.
You could use [JWT](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-jsonwebtoken) instead where users would not need to authenticate. You will only need to obtain consent once. This flow is different and may help address your issue.